# Python: Create a Time series data in required format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Can anybody help to generate the timeseries data in Python in following format.
Date-Month-Year Hours-Min-Sec. from 1st April2020 to 31 March2021 : 01/04/2020 0.00.00 to 31/03/2021 23:50:00

'''
timeseries

```
01/04/2020 0:00:00
01/04/2020 0:10:00
.......
.......



31/03/2021 23:50:00
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use pandas .date_range for that

```
import pandas as pd

start = '2020-04-01 00:00:00'
end = '2021-03-31 23:50:00'
time_series = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='10min')

# formatted time series can be achieved via:
fmt = '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S'
ts_formatted = [i.strftime(fmt) for i in time_series]
```

Take a look at the `fmt` syntax in https://strftime.org/, for the time format needed

Answer (score 1):

I think this code works as you expected

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

start = datetime(year=2020, month=4, day=1)
end = datetime(year=2021, month=4, day=1)

interval = timedelta(minutes=10)

while(start<end):
    print(start.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    start += interval
```